# Bitcoin core make error

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, mac

I am new to bitcoin core development.  I have created a clone using bitcoin core on a mac os mojave 10.14.3. I am have installed all dependencies and am able to run the autogen.sh and configure with no errors. However, when I run make I am getting the following error.

```
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: object: libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-addrdb.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
/opt/local/bin/ar: internal ranlib command failed
make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_server.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

macOS Mojave changes how the header is serialized in the beginning of the executables. Maybe you could tell us how you installed the dependencies (using `brew`?) and the version of the compiler?

Comment: Actually, both `brew` and `macports` were present in my system. I uninstalled `macports` and after that `make` successfully went through, although several warning were generated. Thank you for your help!